# TreeView-Grid control for c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-web-gui

I'm developing a project in Visual webgui right now. Designing a window/page is very similar to WinForms. I need a control like this one: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Tree_List/.

There is no control like this in Gizmox libraries so I have to create my own. I'm looking for source of such a control in WinForms, so I could implement my custom control based on ready example.

Or maybe You have such a control in webgui ? 
Anyway, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You could try [VisualJS.NET](http://visualjs.net) and translate any javascript control easily.. It supports custom javascript based controls etc.